# Is it enough to use a proposed method from the literature and apply it to solve another problem?

Tags: publications, plagiarism

Say, there is a recently proposed machine learning algorithm that you applied to another dataset and you found high performance results.

In general, you found a method that was proposed to solve some task and you apply it to solve another task.

Is this enough for a contribution? Isn't this plagiarism?

Answer (score 3):

It is not plagiarism as long as you properly cite the paper. There are tons of papers titled as follows **[task]** of **[dataset]** using **[method]**. For example, *A, B and C (2077) **Estimating parameters** of **a stochastic cell invasion model with fluorescent cell cycle labelling** using **approximate Bayesian computation**​. Journal of the Royal Society Interface. xx, xxxxxxxx*.

If this is classified as an act of plagiarism, then most research papers are just a product of plagiarism. We more or less *stand (rely) on the shoulders of "giants"*.

Answer (score 3):

It's not plagiarism.

However, if you submit it to a good journal or good conference, it will likely be rejected as not being sufficiently novel for their journal/conference.  A sufficiently low-ranked (but still legitimate) journal/conference will accept it.

(Notice: Novelty is NOT a binary variable.)